# What is the best way to get the item selected in the listview?

Tags: java, android, listview, user-interface

I have a listview which has a bunch of selections. I want to keep the focus on the listview in touchmode and get the item selected. What is the best way to do that?

I found this blog:
http://bestsiteinthemultiverse.com/2009/12/android-selected-state-listview-example/

and 
http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/touch-mode.html

What does the community suggest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't keep focus in touch mode. You can use the "choice mode" instead to keep items checked.

Answer (score 0):

To get an idea of how to use ListView I'd take a look at this Google I/O video. It helped me a lot in getting going and goes over the choice mode (I think).

http://code.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/world-of-listview-android.html